# How to add my own .deb file to my local mirror to use with apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, apt-mirror, localrepository

I've created a full local mirror of the 14.04 repositories using `apt-mirror` and connect to it over LAN using `apache`. I have adapted my sources.list file on the machine that I wish to update from the local mirror.

What is the process required to add my own .deb file (mypackage.deb) and make it available through `apt-get install mypackage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to update your packages in the future, or add new ones, I would strongly recommend not relying on kludges, but instead use the right tools.

So rather than mixing your own packages with a Ubuntu mirror, **consider putting together your own little repo to keep things neat and isolated**, and also sign your packages for authentication.

**This will take a little time to set things up, but will save you a ton of maintenance headaches down the road.**

I've found that the best tool for that  task is `reprepro`.

Some links to get you started:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-reprepro-for-a-secure-package-repository-on-ubuntu-14-04
2. http://kaivanov.blogspot.com.by/2012/08/creating-apt-repository-with-reprepro.html
3. https://wiki.debian.org/SettingUpSignedAptRepositoryWithReprepro

Comment: Then this could be hosted alongside the full local Ubuntu mirror, and wouldn't require much extra apt configuration right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a separate repo you would host alongside your other mirror. Not sure what you mean by "extra apt configuration", could you clarify?

Comment: I just meant any further work on each client machine, other than updating the source.list files. I should probably digest those links first though!

Comment: Correct. You'll just drop a sources file into /etc/apt/sources.list.d with your repo information and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Create a directory and place you .deb package within.

Remind yourself of some of the info present in the debian file:

```
dpkg --info <yourpackage.deb>
```

Move to your directory and enter `sudo dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -c9 > Packages.gz`

Add this line to your `sources.list`: `deb file:///path/to/directory /` - yes, include the whitespace **:)**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I wanted a directory with several of my own debs in, over http, I get that I'd change the 'file' part of the sources line, what else would change, so I don't need to add another line for each package I create?

Comment: @Arronical re-enter the `dpkg-scanpackages` command when you add a new package

Comment: @Arronical I made a mistake - the `file:///` part shouldn't be to the package itself, but to it's parent directory